# Advanced Search in Visual Studio 2008 C# ASP .NET Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, search, web-applications

I just like to ask if anyone knows how to make an advanced search where the user can search the database using a single textbox. In the search, the user can use AND or OR to specifically search records. For example i'd like to search for a person with..
skills in ((basketball OR swimming) AND (baseball or badminton))
.
so the result will show people who knows how to play..

basketball AND baseball

swimming AND badminton

basketball AND badminton

swimming AND baseball

Thank you.. I just really need to know the codes..

Comment: can the user type anything or only some set of commands

Comment: example the user wants to search basketball.. so all people with basketball in the database will appear but if the user types basketball AND badminton then people with basketball AND badminton skills will appear. OR must also be accepted. same as the search box in www.monster.com

Comment: Are you using an ORM? Entity Framework or Linq to SQL?

Comment: I don't know any of the things you said I'm sorry. Im using Visual Studio 2008 c# ASP .net web application, SQL Server 2008 for the databases. And thats all I know. I just put the sql statements in the SqlCommand. Are there shortcuts in making this searchbox? thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dynamic queries and merge your searched text from textbox in query.

like you have a stored procedure like

```
create procedure Test
@SearchClause nvarchar(100) = null
as

declare @qry nvarchar(max)
set @qry = 'select * from TABLE'

if(@SearchClause is not null)
 set @qry = @qry + 'where ' + @SearchClause


exec sp_ExecuteSQL @qry
```

Hope this is what you want?

Comment: what if the parameters and their number and even the sequence change everytime

Comment: You said that user will be putting 'AND' and 'OR' clauses by his own in text box, so in the current procedure, the sequence and count will not be an issue, because you are just sending your where clause from textbox

Comment: about this.. im not really pro so can you explain further? and what codes will I put in c#?

Comment: skills in ((basketball OR swimming) AND (baseball or badminton))....what does this mean then

Comment: See first thing, the logic you are following isnt good, because it increases the chances for sql injection. and also writing 'AND' and 'OR' in textbox by the user, i think we should not expect such behavior from the user, i dont think he knows how to write these 'AND' and 'OR' conditions. so try to make something else, like you can put a check list box, and add your items in it, ASK the user to select items from the list, and then you can get the selected values from the list box and send it to your query.

Comment: @Qasim i was thinking of doing that but I can't think of a way of doing that based on my example ((basketball OR swimming) AND (baseball or badminton)), how can I do that in a single textbox with checkboxes and/or radio buttons thanks for the answers :)